# Querying a payout via Stripe API

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am fetching the contributing transactions for a given payout token via the Stripe API (PHP). The query returns no errors, and shows 9 contributing transactions, all correct. However, the amounts shown did not add up to the total paid into the bank. I logged on to Stripe itself, searched for the given payout token, and was shown a listing of the transactions - except now there were 11! I've repeated the process a number of times, but each time I only get the same 9 transactions via the API instead of the complete 11 I get on their site.

Can anyone point me towards a solution? Is there some reason Stripe would truncate an API response for a single payout? I cannot see any mention of doing so in their documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lay in providing a 'limit' parameter to my request. It defaults to 10.